# Uncaught TypeError: Wrong type for parameter "source" of FileTransfer.download: Expected String, but got Undefined.

Tags: javascript, cordova, amazon-s3

I had asked a question recently about downloading and storing a file locally on the phone. The earlier problem was that I was unable to access the LocalFileSystem. The problem got solved but now I am faced with a new error. I have not seen this error before and am unable to understand it. The code I have so far:

```
 function storeFile(bucketName, csvfile){
     s3Client.getBucketLocation(params = {Bucket: bucketName},function(err,data){
    if(err) console.log("Error :: Cannot retrieve bucket location", err);
    else {
      //console.log(data);
      region = data.LocationConstraint;
      url = "https://s3-" + region + ".amazonaws.com/" + bucketName + "/" + csvfile;  
      //alert(url);
    }
  });

  window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT,0, 
    function(fs){
      //alert(fs.root.fullPath); 
      fs.root.getDirectory("Amazedata", {create: true}, 
        function(d){
          //console.log("got dir");
          filePath = d.fullPath + csvfile;
          //alert(filePath);
          fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
          console.log('downloading to: ', filePath);
          fileTransfer.download(url, filePath, 
            function (entry) {
              console.log(entry.fullPath); // entry is fileEntry object
            }, 
            function (error) {
              console.log("Some error", error.code);
          });
      }, onError);
  }, onRequestError);
}`
```

In the code above, I am able to extract the region and am able to access and create the folder. Problem is that when downloading, it gives me the error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Wrong type for parameter "source" of FileTransfer.download: Expected String, but got Undefined.`

Comment: probably someone of these values not defined: `region, bucketName, csvfile`

Comment: all the values are defined. I was able to print the contents of these variables onto the console.

Comment: I am facing the same problem / error message, but only for certain files. When I try to download a pdf file from URL: http://www.w3.org/2011/web-apps-ws/papers/Nitobi.pdf everything works fine, but when I try to download a pdf file from my Alfresco DMS server, it fails. In both cases though, the response content type is the same: "application/pdf". Did you get a solution to this yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your S3 call is asynchronous. The `url` value won't be defined until that call completes. Move your download code into the `.getBucketLocation` callback.

```
function storeFile(bucketName, csvfile) {
    s3Client.getBucketLocation(params = {
        Bucket: bucketName
    }, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log("Error :: Cannot retrieve bucket location", err);
        else {
            //console.log(data);
            var region = data.LocationConstraint;
            var url = "https://s3-" + region + ".amazonaws.com/" + bucketName + "/" + csvfile;
            //alert(url);

            window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
                function(fs) {
                    //alert(fs.root.fullPath); 
                    fs.root.getDirectory("Amazedata", {
                            create: true
                        },
                        function(d) {
                            //console.log("got dir");
                            var filePath = d.fullPath + csvfile;
                            //alert(filePath);
                            var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
                            console.log('downloading to: ', filePath);
                            fileTransfer.download(url, filePath,
                                function(entry) {
                                    console.log(entry.fullPath); // entry is fileEntry object
                                },
                                function(error) {
                                    console.log("Some error", error.code);
                                });
                        }, onError);
                }, onRequestError);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Tried what you suggested. Am getting source and target errors. `download error source https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bucketname/filename` and ` download error target /Amazedata/filename`

Comment: @PallaviPrasad well I can't test your code unfortunately. The basic problem from your original code was that asynchronous S3 call; there may be other problems.